# Manipulating and changing keys of original array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am currently working with manipulating items in arrays/objects. I have not worked with [lodash](https://lodash.com/) before but after reading how many features this utility tool offer decided to give it a go. The array I would like to modify, involves adding an addtional object `sources` and changing the keys. How can I achieve the below using lodash?

Current Array

```
var myArr = 
[{
    "flv": "myFile.flvs",
    "mp4": "myFile.mp4",
    "webm": "myFile.webm",
    "thumbnail": "poster.png",
    "title": "Test",
    "id": 123456
}];
```

Desired result

```
{
data: [
    {
        sources: [{ 
            file: "myFile.flv"
        },{ 
            file: "myFile.mp4"
        },{
            file: "myFile.webm"
        }],
        image: 'poster.png',
        title: 'Test',
        id: '123456'
    },
    ....
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are there exactly three `testn` properties, or an arbitrary number? Anyway, you just need to write a `transform` function and then do `myArr.data = _.map(myArr.data, transform)`, For `transform`, I suggest writing down the transformation you want to do in English or pseudo-code, and then it should be straightforward to turn it into code.

Comment: @torazaburo its an arbitrary number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var myArr = {
    "data": [{
        "test1": "myFile.flv",
        "test2": "myFile.mp4",
        "test3": "myFile.webm",
        "thumbnail": "poster.png",
        "title": "Test",
        "id": 123456
    }]
};

var result = _.map(myArr.data, function(el) {
    var sources = []
    _.each(el, function(v, k) {
        if (k.match(/test\d*/) !== null) {
            sources.push({
                file: v
            });
        }
    });
    return {
        sources: sources,
        image: el.thumbnail,
        title: el.title,
        id: el.id
    };
});

console.log(result);
```

Result:

[image]

Update per OP request:

```
var EXTENSIONS = ['flv', 'mp4', 'webm'];
var myArr = [{
        "flv": "myFile.flv",
        "mp4": "myFile.mp4",
        "webm": "myFile.webm",
        "thumbnail": "poster.png",
        "title": "Test",
        "id": 123456
    }];

var result = _.map(myArr, function(el) {
    var sources = [];
    _.each(el, function(v, k) {
        if (_.contains(EXTENSIONS, k)) {
            sources.push({
                file: v
            });
        }
    });
    return {
        sources: sources,
        image: el.thumbnail,
        title: el.title,
        id: el.id
    };
});

console.log(result);
```

Note: Here we can use _.contains (which is lodash) or EXTENSIONS.indexOf (which Javascript native).  Since you want to learn lodash, I figure we use _.contains.

Update: Just removed .data from the map function because OP remove the data property from source data.

Comment: I made one modification, instead of the array having `testn` for keys, the keys are `flv`, `mp4` and `webm`.

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student - I see the update, do you have the answer or you still need some help?

Comment: Yes please, could you show how to do it with the keys being different.

Comment: One more helping hand, I had to modify the original array and took out key `data` please see above for update, however now I am getting nothing returned

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student - Simply remove the .data from the map function and everything should work again.  I updated the code in the answer.